# Finding stocks which have hit the bottom and can rise

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

Is there a website or a strategy I can use to identify stocks from various sectors that have hit bottom and will rise in the coming months or weeks? What are the details of the stock that I need to look at to make a good investment?

Comment: If there were, institutional traders would identify them and start buying them before you could react.

Comment: You are basically asking "which stocks will go up?"

Comment: I have a technique, but it requires a Flux Capacitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, for individual stocks, you should be investing in quality companies that are sector leaders with strong and growing free cash flow, low debt, and good management. Buying after pull backs is a good idea but there's no way to know where the bottom is.  No indicator predicts the future which is  unknown.